# How to add string to exisiting file?

Tags: perl

I am a beginner in perl language and I faced the above problem and would like to seek help in it. Much appreciate to all the help.

Given initial File Content:

```
Apple
Pear
Apple
Pear
```

Would like to have the output of:

```
Apple
Pear
Grape
Apple
Pear
Grape
```

Every time after pear is output, would like to add Grape to the output next.

Comment: Please share any code you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only because it's 4 characters shorter than mpapec's solution ;)

```
perl -pe 's/Pear\K/\nGrape/' file1.txt
```

If you really want to learn, try reading: [`How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

Comment: ty, I'm not sure it's deserved since mine will break in the middle of a line.  However, the fix for that `s/Pear.*\K/\nGrape/` still wins by a whole 2 characters.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe '$_ .= "Grape\n" if /Pear/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for offering the help, i tried it out and i somehow manage to solve it by:
Let say my file is in test1.

```
open(DATA,"<test1") or die "No test1 file";
while($data = <DATA>){
    if($data =~ /Pear/){
        $data = $data . "Grape\n";
    }
    print "$data";
}
```